# Is it possible for me to get a shareride from Las Vegas to Yosemite National Park?

Tags: usa, public-transport

We are two Chinese students and want to travel from Las Vegas to Yosemite (if possible also want to travel the Death Valley and Sequoia National Park), how can we get a share ride or is there any commute directly to Yosemite? As far as I know, the normal commute will take 12-14 hours while driving a car would only takes about 6 hours. Fee will be given.

Comment: It is *possible*, for example, to arrange for such a ride on a service like Zimride, or perhaps on a site like Thorntree. This is not a high-volume tourist route, however, and at this time of year I believe the only public transportation to Yosemite is from the California side of the park (Greyound serves Merced, where you can transfer to YARTS). You would be best off renting a car yourself.

Comment: Be sure to look at Mono Lake. The flies are amazing. Really! They swarm thickly along the shore line but will not land on or voluntarily touch people. Astounding to see.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's *possible*.

Your easiest way is probably one of the following:

1. In your accommodation in Vegas, ask around and see if anyone knows someone heading in that direction.
2. Post on forums online, like The Lonely Planet's Thorn Tree forum.
3. The best option, in my view, is to join a rideshare website like [Ridester](http://www.ridester.com/) where ride-sharing types will tend to be, and see if they have something going.

Good luck! It's a beautiful place, and definitely worth getting to, if you can manage it.