# How can I travel flexibly around the US?

Tags: usa, trains, public-transport, buses, greyhound

In Europe, travelers can buy a special rail pass that gives them unlimited train rides for a month. And some airlines offer tickets where a list of destinations is chosen in advance, but the flight dates are flexible and can be chosen on short notice.

Is there anything similar for traveling around the US by bus or train? Greyhound used to offer something like it, called the "Discovery Pass," but it seems to have been discontinued. And Amtrak only seems to offer unlimited passes on specific short routes, mainly targeting commuters.

Comment: @pnuts Not sure I understand the reference.  If you shop around you can get from New York to LA by bus for ~$500 with a few stops NY-LA direct is $319 everything else is us constructing someone's itinerary, which has long been frowned upon.

Comment: @pnuts There have been other questions regarding shared rites on this site.  But again cost will depend on itinerary.  Shorter hops cost more then single long trip between same end points, and again since we are not constructing an itinerary one should already be provided.  Otherwise the question is a duplicate of the one I listed.

Comment: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/12794/list-of-carpooling-services-outside-europe-and-the-us, http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/22704/is-it-possible-for-me-to-get-a-shareride-from-las-vegas-to-yosemite-national-par, http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/6896/nyc-montreal-and-nyc-toronto-overland/6905#6905

Comment: [Relevant literature.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_the_Road)

Comment: @Karlson: Hmm, I don't see what my question has to do with the one it's marked as a duplicate of. The answer to that one says basically "check out grayhound or amtrak," but I've already said in my question that I've examined Greyhound and Amtrak offerings and didn't find anything that matches the criteria I listed. The other questions you link to seem different too - one even specifies "outside the US." I've rewritten my question from scratch to make it hopefully unambiguous and totally different from any other question I can find here - is this better?

Comment: I also cast a reopen vote. The marked duplicate is quite similar and possible helpful, but in no way does it answer this specific question and neither is the question the same at all.

Comment: @MarkMayo: Yes, I think my newly rewritten question is now a duplicate of that one. Thanks!